# CSS: Repeat background image integer number of times

Tags: css, background-image

Can I have a repeating background image that would only be repeated an integer number of times?

```
   li span.counter {
      height: 34px;
      background-repeat: repeat-x;
      background-image: url(home/bk_counter.png);
      letter-spacing: 14px;
      text-indent: 7px;
      display: inline-block;
      color: $text;
      font-weight: 700;
      font-size: 22px;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

[image: example]

Indeed playing with `letter-spacing` property forces me to have the `span` going further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set the background of an element to repleat a set number of times. You'll have to find another option, possibly creating an element for the space you need.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the [Css Multiple Background](http://caniuse.com/multibackgrounds) property, as the example below:

```
 background-image:
   url(logo.png), 
   url(logo.png), 
   url(logo.png), 
   url(logo.png), 
   url(logo.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center 0, center 56px,center 112px, center 168px, center 224px;
```

It works in modern browsers: IE9, Firefox 5+, Chrome 12+, Safari 3.2+, Opera 10.6+.